# How can I use object destruction as parameter in calling a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

I have an object like this:

```
let a = { x: 3, y: '3', z: 'z' };
```

And an array like this:

```
let b = [{ x: 1, y: '1'}, { x: 2, y: '2' }];
```

How can I do something like this:

```
b.push({ x, y } = a);
```

Instead of this:

```
b.push({ x: a.x, y: a.y });

// or this:
const { x, y } = a;
b.push({ x, y });
```

Comment: can be done only by creating a method or using some module like `underscore`
`b.push(_.pick(a, 'x', 'y'))`

Comment: You cannot, is unfortunately the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a new object with the destructured properties.

```js
const
    getXY = ({x, y}) => ({ x, y }),
    a = { x: 3, y: '3', z: 'z' },
    b = [{ x: 1, y: '1'}, { x: 2, y: '2' }];

b.push(getXY(a));

console.log(b);
```

Comment: This is a fairly common mapping pattern where you want to pass an object with some subset of keys/values to some other function. I like naming them `mapTypeAToTypeB`, where TypeA could be (eg) a network response with extraneous data, and TypeB could be what the frontend uses. These can be used standalone or as an `Array.map()` functor.